# Is it correct to say "user redeems an offer"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am writing up technical documentation for a system that involves users receiving different types of offers. Is "User redeems an offer" correct English to describe an event when member participates in a transaction that qualifies for the offer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That makes sense. A user might also "accept an offer" or "participate in an offer". If a user presents some sort of voucher to qualify for the offer, then I'd certainly use "redeem".